# second parenthesis in functions in javascript, what does it mean? what are the use cases?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

for example the connect function from 'react-redux' library, looks something like this:

```
connect(state)(SomeComponent)
```

I understand that connect function accepts a single parameter but what does the second parenthesis mean? It seems like another parameter but why does it have to be in a separate parenthesis? what are the use cases? What exactly is the term for this?

Comment: That explains this but I needed to ask this question to know that the term for this is currying. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, `connect` is a function which returns a function, and then you can call *that* function with something else:

```js
const connect = arg1 => arg2 => arg1 + arg2;
const result = connect(3)(4);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. How do I easily interpret nested functions like this? Like your given example of nested arrow functions, It strains my eyes trying to comprehend at one glance. What are some good use cases?